# How can I control the tab color in the Eclipse Java perspective?

Tags: eclipse, oomph

I'm a relative newcomer to Eclipse. Yesterday via the "Check for Updates" menu item, I installed a couple of minor updates. When Eclipse restarted, in the Java perspective, I noticed that the "Package Explorer" tab now had a dark yellow background, as did the active tab in the view with all the open Java source files. I thought it was a nice improvement. Today, when I restarted Eclipse, the yellow highlights are gone.

Is there an Eclipse preference somewhere that controls this? How can I get the yellow highlights back?

Edit: I found information that this problem is related to Oomph. The "minor updates" mentioned above included Oomph. Since the original post, I've noticed a number of preferences being lost after restarting Eclipse; these may also be related to Oomph. Should I uninstall it?

Comment: In eclipse toolbar, go to Windows -> General -> Appearance. Set theme and color and Font theme. As per the selection, your color combination in eclipse will change. Windows XP Olive theme will give you yellow color. If this is what you want to do, please reply, I will write it as answer.

Comment: This is a valid partial answer; however, see the new information in the edited post.